# nvidia 331.89 super + W causes black window

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

When i am hitting Super + W and choosing one of active window it opens. But when i am mazimizing another minimized window i am getting blank black window, if i minimize then maximize it again it works. Tried 340.24 drivers - but they are totally unusable because of interface corruption in firefox, thunderbird, libreoffice. 331.89 seems stable except this annoying black window.

I am using GTX 750 ti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in nvidia drivers. Waiting for new drivers.